# Values not being passed properly in a linked blocking queue

Tags: java, concurrency

How this works is my can will enter the belt and then will be scanned with the sterilize class, but I have problems as such that my cans are not being passed properly, meaning that some of my cans are not being scanned, eg: Once can 1 is scanned, it says can 2 is added into the belt, but it skips to can 3 straight away

```
public class AsiaPacificFruitFactory {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>beltQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>();
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>sterilizeQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>();

    Belt b = new Belt(beltQ);
    Sterilize s = new Sterilize(beltQ, sterilizeQ);
    b.start();
    s.start();
}

}

   class Belt extends Thread{
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>beltQ;

    public Belt (LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> beltQ){
        this.beltQ = beltQ;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            addCan();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public void addCan(){
        for (int i=1; i<501; i++){
            try{
                beltQ.put(new Can(i));
                System.out.println("Can " + i + " has been added into the belt" );
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }
}

class Scanner implements Callable<Can>{  
    Can c;

    public Scanner (Can c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    Random rand = new Random();

    public Can call() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Scanning can " + c.CanNo + " for dents");
        c.getDefect();

        if(c.defect == 3){
            System.out.println("Can " + c.CanNo + " is dented");
            return null;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Can " + c.CanNo + " is not dented");
            return c;
        }
    }
}

class Sterilize extends Thread{
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>beltQ;
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>sterilizeQ;

    public Sterilize (LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> beltQ, LinkedBlockingQueue<Can>sterilizeQ){
        this.beltQ = beltQ;
        this.sterilizeQ = sterilizeQ;
    }


    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                Can c = beltQ.take();
                ExecutorService exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                Future<Can> tempCan = exe.submit(new Scanner(c));
                if(tempCan.get() == null){
                    System.out.println("Can " + c.CanNo + " has not passed the scanning section");
                    continue;
                }else{
                    sterilizeQ.put(beltQ.take());
                }
            exe.shutdown();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

My output is like this:

```
Can 1 has been added into the belt
Scanning can 1 for dents
Can 1 is not dented
Can 2 has been added into the belt
         Can 1 has passed scanning......proceeding with sterilizing now
Can 3 has been added into the belt
Scanning can 3 for dents
Can 3 is not dented
Can 4 has been added into the belt
         Can 3 has passed scanning......proceeding with sterilizing now
```

Comment: Well, read your code. What does Sterilize do with the can returned by `tempCan.get()`? Also, you're creating a brand new thread pool for each can you get from the queue. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: the sterilizing part is that it is supposed to sterilize the cans but that can only be done after it has been cleared for scanning, and also that threadpool line, because i cant combine a callable with a thread without putting that statement

Comment: You're not answering my question. Look at your code, and answer my question precisely. That will make you find the bug. Create your thread pool once, and only once, in the constructor. You want a single thread pool for all the cans. Not one thread pool per can.

Comment: Well, the only thing you've used the return value is to check null on Callable's return, you never used the value. Additionally, Future#get will _block_ until the future has finished executing; you've lost your multithreaded advantage. I'd also be wary of parallelizing between two different collections (your collections are also blocking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in `Sterilize` `run` method

Replace

```
sterilizeQ.put(beltQ.take());
```

with

```
sterilizeQ.put(c);
```